# Why doesn't this code output anything?

Tags: c

Consider this "EXAM" question:

```
int main()
{
   int a=10,b=20;
   char x=1,y=0;
   if(a,b,x,y)
   {
      printf("EXAM");
   }
}
```

Please let me know why this doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: Hi Gollum, I'm surprised to see you here. Anyway, for me the output isn't `"Printed Nothing"` and I don't see a C question being outputted either...

Answer (score 11):

[Comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) - evaluates 1st expression and returns the second one. So `a,b,x,y` will return value stored in y, that is 0.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `a,b,x,y` is `y` (because the comma operator evaluates to the result of its right operand) and y is 0, which is false.

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator returns the last statement, which is `y`.  Since `y` is zero, the if-statement evaluates to false, so the `printf` is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Because expression `a,b,x,y` evaluates to `y`, which in turn evaluates to `0`, so corresponding block is never executed. Comma operator executes every statement and returns value of last one. If you want logical conjunction, use `&&` operator:

```
if (a && b && x && y) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Others already mentioned that the comma operator returns the right-most value. If you want to get the value printed if ANY of these variables is true use the logical or:

```
int main()
{
   int a=10,b=20;
   char x=1,y=0;
   if(a || b || x || y)
   {
      printf("EXAM");
   }
 }
```

But then be aware of the fact that the comma evaluates all expressions whereas the or operator stops as soon as a value is true. So with

```
int a = 1;
int b;
if(a || b = 1) { ... }
```

b has an undefined value whereas with

```
int a = 1;
int b;
if(a, b = 1) { ... }
```

b will be set to 1.